# ExecuteScalar method to retrieve SQL Server 2019 table column list in Visual Studio 2019 c-sharp is incorrectly ASCII sorted

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, columnsorting, executescalar

I have a table in my SQL Server database with the following stucture:

```
CREATE TABLE [file].[NumeTestINV](
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Class] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Company] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Division] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Jan] [float] NULL,
    [Feb] [float] NULL,
    [Mar] [float] NULL,
    [Apr] [float] NULL,
    [May] [float] NULL,
    [Jun] [float] NULL,
    [Jul] [float] NULL,
    [Aug] [float] NULL,
    [Sep] [float] NULL,
    [Oct] [float] NULL,
    [Nov] [float] NULL,
    [Dec] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am trying to retrieve its column list via C# code in a Visual Studio 2019 SSIS Script Task.  I have the following code c-sharp snippet.

```
//Get Matching Column List from SQL Server
string SQLColumnList = "";
SqlCommand cmd = myADONETConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = SQLQueryToGetMatchingColumn;
SQLColumnList = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
MessageBox.Show(" Matching Columns: " + SQLColumnList);
```

However, the problem is that the column list is being outputted incorrectly sorted in ASCII.  I am not sure why my SQLColumnList is not coming out with the correct SQL table column order as it is physically and, instead is is coming out as the following?

```
"[Apr],[Aug],[Category],[Class],[Company],[Dec],[Division],[Feb],[Jan],[Jul],[Jun],[Mar],[May],[Nov],[Oct],[Sep]"
```

I was expecting the following output:

```
"[Category],[Class],[Company],[Division],[Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec]"
```

Here is the code for SQLQueryToGetMatchingColumn, my source is an Excel file with the same column list in the same order as my physical SQL table:

```
SQLQueryToGetMatchingColumn = "select STUFF((Select  ',['+Column_Name+']' from Information_schema.Columns where Table_Name='" +
                            TableName + "' and Table_SChema='" + SchemaName + "'" +
                            "and Column_Name in (" + @ExcelHeaderColumn + ") for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS ColumnList";
```

Here is the output for SQLQueryToGetMatchingColumn:

```
"select STUFF((Select  ',['+Column_Name+']' from Information_schema.Columns where Table_Name='NumeTestINV' and Table_SChema='file'and Column_Name in ('Category','Class','Company','Division','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec') for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS ColumnList"
```

The CommandText output is the following:

```
"select STUFF((Select  ',['+Column_Name+']' from Information_schema.Columns where Table_Name='NumeTestINV' and Table_SChema='file'and Column_Name in ('Category','Class','Company','Division','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec') for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS ColumnList"
```

I am hoping that this is a small code change in my snippet and that I don't have to completely change the method by which I am retrieving my SQL Column list.

Comment: And what is the code for `SQLQueryToGetMatchingColumn`?

Comment: What is the CommandText?

Comment: Order in SQL is an illusion you have in your mind, unless you use a ORDER BY complete enough. Without the ORDER BY the SQL is free to return the rows in any order.

Comment: Hi Charlieface, `SQLQueryToGetMatchingColumn = "select STUFF((Select  ',['+Column_Name+']' from Information_schema.Columns where Table_Name='" +
                            TableName + "' and Table_SChema='" + SchemaName + "'" +
                            "and Column_Name in (" + @ExcelHeaderColumn + ") for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS ColumnList";`

Comment: Hi jdwend, 
`CommandText = "select STUFF((Select  ',['+Column_Name+']' from Information_schema.Columns where Table_Name='NumeTestINV' and Table_SChema='file'and Column_Name in ('Category','Class','Company','Division','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec') for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS ColumnList"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the columns in order, try something like this:

```
select string_agg( quotename(name), ', ') within group (order by columnproperty(c.object_id, c.name, 'ordinal') ) columnList
from sys.columns c
where c.object_id = object_id('[file].[NumeTestINV]')
```

or

```
select string_agg( quotename(column_name), ', ') within group (order by ordinal_position) columnList
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'file'
  and TABLE_NAME = 'NumeTestINV'
```

or with the old XML conatenation,

```
select STUFF((Select  ','+ quotename(Column_Name) from Information_schema.Columns where Table_Name='NumeTestINV' and Table_SChema='file'and Column_Name in ('Category','Class','Company','Division','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec') order by ordinal_position for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS ColumnList
```

Comment: David, this was EXACTLY what I was looking for!  I had ended up simply adding your suggested 'order by ordinal_position' to my SQLQueryToGetMatchingColumn definition.